# How to let my website tell what current day it is alongside with a nice string message?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm doing a javascript lab where my website user can simply click a button and the website will make an alert that first will show the date regularly and then the day with a string message.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function dateFunction() {
        var date = new Date();
        var daysOfweek= ["Sunday", 
"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday", "Saturday"];
        alert(date);
        var currentday = date.getDay();
        alert("Happy " + weekdays[currentday] + "!");


    }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a variable to get the day in number format. Today is Friday which is 5

Your `weekdays[currentday]` returns nothing because you didn't call it weekdays you called it daysOfweek

```
    function dateFunction() {
        var date = new Date();
        var daysDigitized = date.getDay();
        var weekdays= ["Sunday", "Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday", "Saturday"];
        alert(date);
        var currentday = date.getDay();
        alert("Happy " + weekdays[daysDigitized] + "!");
    }
```

**Lastly, you never asked a question. I had to run your code to figure out there was a problem and what the problem was. So, really I'm just assuming this is what you need. Next time be sure and ask a specific question.**

Updated per comments

Comment: There's a bug in the code and it won't run properly.  To resolve, change "d.getDay();" to "date.getDay();" in the 2nd line in the function.

Comment: Is that a browser thing because this works for me in chrome

Comment: No, it's definitely a bug (and does not run as-is in Chrome) as the code is attempting to use a variable ("d") that has not been defined in the line "var daysDigitized = d.getDay();"   The line above it has defined and set a variable called "date" and that's what needs to be used instead of "d".  In summary, I would update the answer to change "var daysDigitized = d.getDay();" to "var daysDigitized = date.getDay();".